# Is the using `int` is more preferably than the using of `unsigned int`?

Tags: c++, int, unsigned

If I use `int`, then sometimes I am to do additional checking of arguments:

```
class Bad_Value{};
class Value_Overflow{};

int get_area(int a, int b){
  // check arguments
  if (a < 0 || b < 0){
    throw Bad_Value();
  }

  int c = a * b; // the work

  // check the result
  if (b != c / a){
    throw Value_Overflow();
  }
  return c;
}
```

If I will use `unsigned int` instead of `int` then at such cases my code will be more compact:

```
class Value_Overflow{};

unsigned int get_area(unsigned int a, unsigned int b){
  // arguments checking is not necessary now
  unsigned int c = a * b; // the work

  // check the result
  if (b != c / a){
    throw Value_Overflow();
  }
  return c;
}
```

But sometimes I had read in some old books what the using `int` is more preferably than the using of `unsigned int`. It is still actual?

Comment: I know Bjarne Stroustrup says to use an int unless you need the extra range unsigned gives you.

Comment: I would say it actual for `C` language as it don't have exceptions to indicate error.

Comment: @NathanOliver yes, I meaned his book (Programming. Principles and Practice Using C++).